# Metadata service Invalid Session Id on future method

Tags: apex, metadata-api, soap, httprequest, session-id

I'm making a call to the Metadata service API.
The Api call happens in future methods.
I have tried both approaches of passing the Session Id as a parameter to the future method and also getting the Session Id inside the future method.

But still either way I keep on receiving Invalid Session Id. This doesn't happen always in all org. Either of them work.

SessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId()

Api URL:http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata

Could you please let me know what is wrong here

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How is the session ID invalid? Is it expired?

Comment: I get this error 
FATAL_ERROR System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the API faultcode=sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID faultactor=

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get the session Id in Apex without using `UserInfo.getSessionId()`. There are instructions here: https://www.codeinstance.com/2020/03/how-to-get-session-id-in-future-methods.html

Comment: I have tried the first approach, it works sometimes. But not always or on different orgs.
@future(callout=true)
  global static void methodName(String sessionId) {

Comment: The second approach is not feasible. As it needs to store user credentials